# How to use `regex` to add % sign to a string only for specific strings that don't have it

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I am trying to add **%** sign to numbers in the range of 0 to 10 in my data frame using `regex`. The data frame is like the one shown below:

```
structure(list(comment = c("3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.15% BALANCE", 
"3.25%  1ST $100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE", "3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.16  BALANCE", 
"3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.15%  BALANCE", "3.26-100 AND 1.16", "3.26-100 AND 1.16"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

1 3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.15% BALANCE  
2 3.25%  1ST $100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE
3 3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.16  BALANCE   
4 3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.15%  BALANCE  
5 3.26-100 AND 1.16                    
6 3.26-100 AND 1.16
```

So basically, I only want to add **%** to 1.16 in row 3 and 3.26 and 1.16 in rows 5 and 6. I wrote the code shown below:

```
tt$modified <- gsub("([0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9])", "\\1%", tt$comment)
```

but as it's shown below, this will add **%** to all numbers:

```
  comment                               modified                               
  <chr>                                 <chr>                                  
1 3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.15% BALANCE   3.22%%-1ST $100000 AND 1.15%% BALANCE  
2 3.25%  1ST $100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE 3.25%%  1ST $100000 AND 1.16%%  BALANCE
3 3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.16  BALANCE    3.22%% 1ST 100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE   
4 3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.15%  BALANCE   3.22%% 1ST 100000 AND 1.15%%  BALANCE  
5 3.26-100 AND 1.16                     3.26%-100 AND 1.16%                    
6 3.26-100 AND 1.16                     3.26%-100 AND 1.16%
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may make judicious use of lookarounds here to ensure that the percent sign only gets added where you want it:

```r
df$comment <- gsub("\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\b(?![%.])", "\\1%", df$comment, perl=TRUE)
df

                                comment
1   3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.15% BALANCE
2 3.25%  1ST $100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE
3   3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE
4   3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.15%  BALANCE
5                   3.26%-100 AND 1.16%
6                   3.26%-100 AND 1.16%
```

Note that I assume here that you *only* want to target decimal numbers.  If you also might want to target integers, then we would need more information about the context of all replacements.

The regex pattern says to:

```
\b            match a word boundary (start of the number)
(             capture
    \d+\.\d+  a number with a decimal component
)             end capture
\b            word boundary
(?![%.])      assert that what follows is NOT % or .
```

Note that the final negative lookahead prevents replacements from being made on numbers which already have `%`, or the integer component of of a decimal number.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. This solution does answer my question partially. Actually, it didn't change 3.26 in row 5 and 6 to 3.26%. Is there any way to modify it such that it also changes those two numbers?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you Sorry, I didn't see that you wanted to also make that replacement.  Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is working now. For my reference, I got every detail of your code, except `(?![%.])`. Can you elaborate more on that? or refer me to a reference to read and understand what is `(?![%.])` doing in the code?

Comment: It says to _assert_ (true or false) that what follows is _not_ `%` or `.` ... this means that replacement will _not_ happen for numbers which already have `%`, or the integer component of a decimal number.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with an optional `%` sign to remove double `%`.

```
tt$modified <- gsub("([0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9])%?", "\\1%", tt$comment)
tt

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  comment                               modified                             
#  <chr>                                 <chr>                                
#1 3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.15% BALANCE   3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.15% BALANCE  
#2 3.25%  1ST $100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE 3.25%  1ST $100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE
#3 3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.16  BALANCE    3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.16%  BALANCE  
#4 3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.15%  BALANCE   3.22% 1ST 100000 AND 1.15%  BALANCE  
#5 3.26-100 AND 1.16                     3.26%-100 AND 1.16%                  
#6 3.26-100 AND 1.16                     3.26%-100 AND 1.16%
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah, this solution also works and it's easy to understand. Thanks for sharing it with me